# Optimize solution for the given coding problem

Tags: list, scala, recursion, optimization

I am a newbie in Scala and I am trying to resolve the following simple coding problem:

> Write a listOfLists recursive method that takes a number of strings as varargs and then
> creates a list of lists of strings, with one less string in each, so for example:
> `listOfLists("3","2","1")` should give back: `List(List("3","2","1"), List("2","1"), List("1"))`

The solution I've found is the following:

```scala
def listOfLists(strings: String*): List[List[String]] = {
      val strLength = strings.length

      @tailrec
      def recListOfList(result: List[List[String]], accumulator: Int): List[List[String]] = {
          accumulator match {
            case x if x < strLength =>
              recListOfList(result :+ (strings.toList.takeRight(strings.length - accumulator)), accumulator + 1 )
            case _ => result
          }
        }

      val res: List[List[String]] = List(strings.toList)
      recListOfList(res, 1)
}
```

The solution works, however I think it could be written much more better.
A problem I can see is that I convert the varargs to a List with the toList method, but a hint that the problem gave me is to use the eta expansion **_*** but I don't know how to use it in this context.

Then, I tried to find another way to write in a more efficient way the following instruction:

```
strings.toList.takeRight(strings.length - accumulator))
```

but this is the only solution that came up in my mind.

Any review is welcome (also say that this solution is a total mess :D (providing the right reasons))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This meets all the specified requirements.

```
def listOfLists(strings: String*): List[List[String]] =
  if (strings.isEmpty) Nil
  else strings.toList :: listOfLists(strings.tail:_*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```scala
def listOfLists(strings: String*): List[List[String]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[String], acc: List[List[String]]): List[List[String]] =
    remaining match {
      case head :: tail =>
        loop(remaining = tail, (head :: tail) :: acc)
      
      case Nil =>
        acc.reverse
    }
  
  loop(remaining = strings.toList, acc = List.empty)
}
```

I believe the code is self-explanatory; but, feel free to ask any questions you may have.

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/TIsxl3m5QWWgypTIrJeLgw/1)*.

Answer (score 1):

Not a recursive method but worth noting that `tails` in the standard library can do most of this. Then map and filter to convert to correct type and filter out empty list.

```
def listOfLists(strings: String *): List[List[String]] = strings.tails.map(_.toList).filter(_.nonEmpty).toList
```

Test:

```
scala> listOfLists("a","b","c")
val res6: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, b, c), List(b, c), List(c))
```

Comment: It would be better to call `toList` before the `tails` to avoid calling `.map(_.toList)`

Answer (score 0):

From Scala 2.13 you can use [`List.unfold`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#unfold%5BA,S%5D(init:S)(f:S=%3EOption%5B(A,S)%5D):CC%5BA%5D) and [`Option.when`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.5/scala/Option$.html#when%5BA%5D(cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option%5BA%5D):

```scala
def listOfLists(strings: String*): List[List[String]] = {
  List.unfold(strings) { s =>
    Option.when(s.nonEmpty)(s.toList, s.tail)
  }
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ED1ESQBnR1CEwKnTnB0JLg).

Comment: I guess the exercise is meant to be solved using tail-recursion.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez! So I modified to another answer, which can work.

Answer (score 0):

Using almost the same idea you can rewrite your solution in cleaner way:

```scala
def listOfLists(strings: String*): List[List[String]] = {
      @tailrec
      def recListOfList(curr: List[String], accumulator: Seq[List[String]]): Seq[List[String]] = {
          curr match {
            case head :: tail => recListOfList(tail, curr +: accumulator)
            case _ => accumulator
          }
        }

      recListOfList(strings.toList, Nil)
        .reverse
        .toList
}
```

With the splat(`_*`) operator, which adapts a sequence (Array, List, Seq, Vector, etc.) to varargs parameter you can create a shorter solution, but it will not be tail-recursive:

```scala
def listOfLists(strings: String*): List[List[String]] = {
  val curr = strings.toList
  curr match {
   case Nil => Nil    
   case x :: tail => curr :: listOfLists(tail:_*)
  }  
}
```

Comment: ^^ `curr :: listOfLists1(tail:_*)`

Comment: @Dima thanks, was plaing a little bit with solution and lost it =))